# Configure SSL/TSL Version and CIpher Suites on iOS (iPad/iPhone)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, ssl

**TLDR**: Is there any way to configure iOS SSL cipher suites for a mobile-device-initiated, REST-over-TLS network connection, without using non-iOS-native HTTP or SSL libraries.  If so, where is the API documented and are there any examples?

**Details**: I am working with others to develop an iOS mobile application and we are unable to locate details about how to force the native iOS crypto libraries to use a specific version of SSL/TLS, or specific cipher suites.  This is for a custom REST application, so the approach would have to be possible to connect via HTTP over TLS.

The app is written in Objective-C.  We are trying to stay within iOS native functionality without including a separate SSL/TLS library.

I did try to search for an answer on SO, but I didn't find anything that seemed to cover the question.